# Match first value between two csv source and return line in one output file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Is there any way to find a match value in delimited source file and output match to CSV? So it will search the first value in source file and try and match the first value in match file. Then it would output the whole line that match to output file.

**Source file:**

> ```
> 12341234 |John Wayne |1234 |Halo | 
> 11111111 |Harambe |421 |Zoo | 
> 22222222 |Scary S |4569 |Test |
> ```

**Match file:**

> ```
> 11111111, John H 
> 22222222, Scary Smithen
> ```

**Output:**

> ```
> 11111111 |Harambe |421 |Zoo | 
> 22222222 |Scary S |4569 |Test |
> ```

Comment: Is that an example of the actual numbers used in the first field, or are the numbers all unique and always have 8 characters?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what particular part do you have problems with? Please share your efforts! And please clarify what you want (the title says VBScript only, the tags say more)...

Comment: @aschipfl previously I was using batch [jgrep.bat](https://gist.github.com/krowe/da2a6b021ac891f8e3be) to find match for 1 value in a source file as here [link](http://superuser.com/questions/822405/how-to-search-for-a-certain-keyword-that-match-the-variable-in-batch-file). For this time I'm going to search for multiple value. Any solution from batch or vbscript will do or just point me to an example of similar process I will proceed from there.

Comment: @Randy-Schuman all number is unique and always have 8 char.

Comment: I removed "VBScript" from the title to avoid confusion (the tags are enough). Anyway, please post what you have tried describe and describe precisely where you are stuck by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39263957/edit) the question! Otherwise this is nothing but a task request, which is off-topic here as StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here!

Comment: A starting point for [tag:batch-file]: [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (you may even nest them), [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [`echo`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html), [`sort`](http://ss64.com/nt/sort.html), [substring replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) and [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Answer (score 0):

Learn about ADO connection to text files (starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)) and SQL Joins (starting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))). Clean up your text format (one char separators (not multi char (" |") delimiters, strings quoted, one format for all) and describe your files/tables using a [schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx) file. For my sample I used:

```
;
[a.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
CharacterSet=1252
Format=Delimited(|)
col1=d LONG
col2=e TEXT
col3=f LONG
col4=g TEXT

[b.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
CharacterSet=1252
Format=Delimited(|)
col1=d LONG
col2=e TEXT

[c.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
CharacterSet=1252
Format=Delimited(|)
col1=d LONG
col2=e TEXT
col3=f LONG
col4=g TEXT
```

My a.txt:

```
12341234|"John Wayne"|1234|"Halo"
11111111|"Harambe"|421|"Zoo"
22222222|"Scary S"|4569|"Test"
```

In your code, open an [ADODB.CONNECTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681519(v=vs.85).aspx) to the folder your files reside in and execute an SQL statement like

```
SELECT A.* FROM [b.txt] AS B, [a.txt] AS A WHERE B.d = A.d
```

to get the desired data; resp.

```
"SELECT A.* INTO [c.txt] FROM [b.txt] AS B, [a.txt] AS A WHERE B.d = A.d"
```

to put the selection into a file c.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any research on your own, I decided to provide [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solutions, based on most of the commands and techniques I referred to in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263957/match-first-value-between-two-csv-source-and-return-line-in-one-output-file#comment65867869_39263957) above.

The main idea for the following script is to nest two `for /F` loops, each one reading one of the two input files; the outer loop reads the source file (`|`-separated table), the inner one the CSV match file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "SOURCEFILE=%~dp0table.txt"
set "MATCHFILE=%~dp0match.csv"
set "TARGETFILE=con"

> "%TARGETFILE%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%SOURCEFILE%") do (
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=| " %%N in ("%%L") do (
            for /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%F in ("%MATCHFILE%") do (
                if "%%N"=="%%F" (
                    echo %%L
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This is quite simple, but there is a great disadvantage: for every single line of the source file, the whole CSV file is read and parsed, so there are a lot of file access operations in case of a huge source file.

To avoid that, the CSV file needs to be read into memory once before processing the source file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "SOURCEFILE=%~dp0table.txt"
set "MATCHFILE=%~dp0match.csv"
set "TARGETFILE=con"

set /A "MATCHCOUNT=0"
for /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%F in ("%MATCHFILE%") do (
    set /A "MATCHCOUNT+=1"
    call set "MATCHNUM[%%MATCHCOUNT%%]=%%F"
)

> "%TARGETFILE%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%SOURCEFILE%") do (
        set "SOURCELINE=%%L"
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=| " %%N in ("%%L") do (
            set "SOURCENUM=%%N"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            for /L %%I in (1,1,%MATCHCOUNT%) do (
                if "!SOURCENUM!"=="!MATCHNUM[%%I]!" (
                    echo !SOURCELINE!
                )
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach reads and parses the CSV file at the beginning and stores the values from the first column into array-like environment variables `MATCHNUM[]`, which are then used for searching the source file.